# How to read a CSV file and do operations on the data?

Tags: java, csv, object, data-structures

I have a CSV file that contains the following: user_id, order_id, # of items. I will read in the file and do operations with the data, for example: Find the number of unique user_id, the average # of items bought per user, etc... What is the best way to approach this? What data structure will I use? I was thinking to create an object for each line/data set, then adding it to a linked list, but I am not sure if that's how it's done. I am using Java.

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are several tutorials out there on how to read a CSV file in Java. Use Google. Come back if you have a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can handle this.

One is to "deserialize" each row to an object. For example, if you have `user_id,item_purchased,user`, then you could have an object with the same 3 fields. You then create an instance of the object for each row, populate it from the CSV file, and add it to your collection class.

Another possibility is to create an object that represents the row itself (i.e. headers, fields, etc.), but I think that that would probably be inferior in this case because you're planning on operating on the data, not the CSV rows. From the perspective of the rest of your program, you don't care where the data comes from, just what the data itself is.